# Spring MVC 4 Upload File Blocked by Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

Im trying upload file in my Spring MVC 4 project via Spring Form, but when I submit form with my log say : `Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@527de1e2` and `Invalid CSRF token found`.

And I found solution from [Spring Security Reference](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.1.x/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-multipart)
, but After I placing Multipart Filter before Spring security, my Model Attrbute are returning NULL.

Here is my codes :

**JSP Snippet :**

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>

<html>
<body>
<div>
    <form:form action="save?${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}"
    method="post" modelAttribute="book" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table>
            <form:input type="hidden" path="id" />
            <tr>
                <td>ISBN:</td>
                <td><form:input path="isbn" autofocus="autofocus"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Title:</td>
                <td><form:input path="title" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Author:</td>
                <td><form:input path="author" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Publisher:</td>
                <td><form:input path="publisher" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Call Number:</td>
                <td><form:input path="callNumber" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Pages:</td>
                <td><form:input path="pages" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Pages:</td>
                <td><form:input path="imageFile" type="file" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
</div>
```

**Model**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="books")
public class Book implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 4235334951865878125L;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private int id;

  @NotNull
  @NotEmpty
  @Size(min = 1, max = 25)
  @Column(name = "isbn")
  private String isbn;

  @NotNull
  @NotEmpty
  @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
  @Column(name = "title")
  private String title;

  @Size(max = 50)
  @Column(name = "author")
  private String author;

  @Size(max = 50)
  @Column(name = "publisher")
  private String publisher;

  @Size(max = 25)
  @Column(name = "call_number")
  private String callNumber;

  @Column(name = "pages")
  private int pages;

  @Column(name = "image_file")
  private byte[] imageFile;

  //Setter & Getter
}
```

**Controller Snippet :**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('BOOK_ADD', 'BOOK_EDIT')")
public String saveBook(@ModelAttribute @Valid Book book, BindingResult result) {
    bookValidator.validate(book, result);

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "book/form";
    }
    if (bookService.getBook(book.getId()) == null) {
        bookService.save(book);
    } else {
        bookService.update(book);
    }
    return "redirect:/book";
}
```

**Servlet Configuration :**

```
@Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver resolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    resolver.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return resolver;
}
```

**Spring Security Initializer :**

```
@Override
protected void beforeSpringSecurityFilterChain(ServletContext servletContext) {
    insertFilters(servletContext, new MultipartFilter());
}
```

**SQL Table :**

```
CREATE TABLE `books` (
  `id` INT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `isbn` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  `title` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `author` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `publisher` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `call_number` VARCHAR(25) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `pages` INT(5) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_file` MEDIUMBLOB NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

and **Library Snippet Im Using :**

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
   <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency.
   <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
   <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
   <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
   <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
   <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a new MultipartFile attribute in Book class like what other people suggest, and make it transient. When this attribute is set, and set your imageFile as well.

```
@Column(name = "image_file")
private byte[] imageFile;

@Transient
private MultipartFile multiPartFile;

public void setMultiPartFile(MultipartFile multiPartFile) {
    this.multiPartFile = multiPartFile;
    if(multiPartFile != null){
        this.setImageFile(multiPartFile.getBytes());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @simon-l, it's nice solution. but I have found same solution with make method InitBinder annotation to convert MultipartFile type to byte[] in controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try it by changing

`private byte[] imageFile;`

to

```
private MultipartFile imageFile;
```

**Update**

If  you are using blob datatype in DB,you receive the file using `MultipartFile` from front end and then have another getter setter with byte[].

```
private MultipartFile imageFileFrntEnd;
// getter
public MultipartFile setImageFileFrntEnd(MultipartFile file){
   //convert to byte[] and set to imageFile
}

private byte[] imageFile;
//getter setter
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But if I change to `MultipartFile` i get this error :  org.hibernate.MappingException

Answer (score 0):

Arip Hidayat,

I think you need to edit some code.

very simple java + spring mvc file upload

config .xml

```
<!-- MultipartResolver -->
<bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="-1" />
    <property name="maxInMemorySize" value="-1" />
</bean>

<!-- BeanNameViewResolver -->
<bean id="downloadViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver">
    <property name="order">
        <value>0</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Html

```
<form id="upload_form" action="/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <label>file : </label> 
     <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
     <input type="submit" value="upload" />
</form>
```

Model

```
public class MultipartFileModel {


private MultipartFile file;

//...getter, setter
```

}

It is important.

**input tag name = "file"**

**model MultipartFile variable name = "file"**

Controller

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/upload")
    private ModelAndView writeFile(MultipartFileModel model) {

        MultipartFile multipartfile = model.getFile();
        // you use "multipartfile"
        // ... you write file
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But if I change to `MultipartFile` type I get hibernate mapping exeption. Have you any suggesttion if I use spring form tld?

Comment: You use DB in imgfile? Just save filePath in db, save imgfile in server local. You maintain entity class and change vriable name String imgfilepath. You add class model. use model in controller.

Comment: Yes, I save file into DB as blob.